# arborjs solve canvas blurry text due to mouse event doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am using [arborjs](http://arborjs.org) on my project. The text in **canvas** created by `fillText` **html5**. Everything works fine on Retina display macbook, but the text looks blurry.  So i got a solution like below:

```
var pixelRatio      = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

  canvas.style.width  = canvas.width +'px';
  canvas.style.height = canvas.height +'px';

  canvas.width  *= pixelRatio;
  canvas.height *= pixelRatio;
```

Yes, it works. But the drag and click doesn't work.

The issue should be the node of arborjs node draws at the half place, so i tried to make the mouse point map to half of the canvas:

```
_mouseP *= 0.5
_mouseP *= 0.5
nearest = dragged = particleSystem.nearest(_mouseP);
```

Not works. Anyone has this experience help thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it by set the screenSize to constant

```
particleSystem.screenSize(800, 600)
```